# SQL/SAP HANA SQL DATATYPES

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, hana

I need to know how can i get an 'E' to appear for each of the columns when the sum of all these columns = 0. I've tried case when <...> then 'E' but i keep getting "SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number: not a valid number string 'E'"

i figure its because of the data types, the column seems to be in DOUBLE or INT
Please help. Thanks

```
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_airConditioning"),2) AS "CB_Cooling($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_refrigeration"),2) AS "CB_Fridges & Freezers($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_waterHeating"),2) AS "CB_Electric Hot Water($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_cooking"),2) AS "CB_Cooking($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_laundry"),2) AS "CB_Laundry & Dishwasher($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_lighting"),2) AS "CB_Lighting($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_entertainment"),2) AS "CB_Home Entertainment($)",
ROUND((EBD."Disagg Charge"*ID."perc_pool"),2) AS "CB_Pool Pump($)",
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face here is that the **output** data type needs to be fixed when you write your SQL statement. SQL is statically typed, so the result cannot be `DOUBLE` for non-zero values and `STRING` for zero values.

So, if you want to have the described behaviour, making the output column a `STRING` type is the only option you have here. One consequence of this is that whatever client application reads this result, will not be able to understand that this column is *mainly* a `DOUBLE` data type (e.g. formatting becomes a lot harder and further computation likely will require another data type change). If you're comfortable with this, then go ahead...

Here's how such code can look like in SAP HANA:

```
with some_data as (
                select 'A' as add_group, 1.2 as mynumber from dummy
    union all   select 'A' as add_group, 4.523 as mynumber from dummy
    union all   select 'A' as add_group, 3.23 as mynumber from dummy
    union all   select 'B' as add_group, 3.5 as mynumber from dummy
    union all   select 'B' as add_group, -1.75 as mynumber from dummy
    union all   select 'B' as add_group, -1.75 as mynumber from dummy
)
select 
    add_group, sum(mynumber),
    case 
        when (sum (mynumber) = 0.0)
            then 'E'
        else 
            to_varchar( sum (mynumber))
    end as err_sum
from 
    some_data
group by add_group;


ADD_GROUP   SUM(MYNUMBER)   ERR_SUM
A           8.953           8.953
B           0               E
```